# Message alert in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, alert, messagebox

How to implement a message box like a alert box when button gets clicked or tiles get tapped.
also messagebox or alertbox contain buttons into my windows phone 8 application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take a look at the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ms598690%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

There you can get an example and further details about `MessageBox.Show Method (String, String, MessageBoxButton)`:

```
MessageBoxResult result = 
    MessageBox.Show("Would you like to see the simple version?", 
    "MessageBox Example", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
{
    MessageBox.Show("No caption, one button.");
}
```

Or a overview about the whole [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/System.Windows.MessageBox%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class.

Comment: thankxxx get it but how we can implement a rate & review dialogue box to our application. like it will open automatically one time in two days.

Comment: I don't know how to do this. Actually take a look [here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Implement_%22Rate_My_App%22_in_under_60_seconds). It is about implementing a rating for an app. Maybe this a start for you to go on from.

Answer (score 4):

To show an alert you can use,

```
MessageDialog msgbox = new MessageDialog("Message to be displayed.");  
await msgbox.ShowAsync();
```